# Is it possible to catch unauthorized error through websocket via StompJS (ng2Stomp)?

Tags: angular, websocket, stompjs

I'm using StompJS [ng2-stompjs](https://stomp-js.github.io/ng2-stompjs/) in Angular. Requests go through JWT authentication.

I have written an HttpInterceptor that logs out the user when any http response returns with an error 401. I would like to implement a similar behavior with websocket. My application only uses websocket communication on some pages so I cannot track if their token expired.
I also have to use Stomp because I have to subscribe to topics and as far as I know it isn't possible via the standard typescript or rxjs websockets.

So the issue is the following:
When the token is wrong, I can see the following error in the console:

> client.js:274 WebSocket connection to 'ws://...' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available

Stomp also notifies me in the console about the connection being closed if I have debug mode enabled. However I'd like to know on code level when I get such an auth error.

In this ng2stomp implementation I can only find a `webSocketErrors$` subject that notifies me when this error happens, but it only sends back a typescript `Event` with no relevant data.

From this error I cannot tell whether there was a sudden loss of connection, or maybe a backend error, or the user is actually unauthorized, thus I cannot force a logout when I catch this.

I haven't tried using the standard StompJS library yet, but I'm not sure it's possible to catch this error with it. I also don't know if there is any other way to subscribe to topics other than using Stomp, because this is the only solution I found so far.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am attempting to answer without writing working code.

There are several points:

- Websocket connections, even though over HTTP does not use the same HTTP stack as normal HTTP connections. Angular's HTTP Interceptors would not intercept these calls.
- There is no documented way to add HTTP headers to a WebSocket connection request.
- A reliable way to add authentication credentials would be the STOMP connection headers - https://stomp-js.github.io/api-docs/latest/classes/RxStompConfig.html#connectHeaders
- If you need to acquire or refresh tokens, you may use https://stomp-js.github.io/api-docs/latest/classes/RxStompConfig.html#beforeConnect
- If you are using SockJS, refer to https://stomp-js.github.io/guide/stompjs/rx-stomp/ng2-stompjs/using-stomp-with-sockjs.html as well.

ng2-stompjs is a thin wrapper over the StompJs, so, capability wise both are not likely to be different.